# Edge Animate Glitch in Firefox Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

I'm using adobe edge animate to create this site:
http://www.reveriesrefined.com/myftp/5/

It was working fine on a windows machine, but I got onto a mac to start making some changes and firefox is having some problems. It works exactly as expected for safari, and yesterday it was working fine on all browsers. Basically, when the page loads and the divs move out from behind the pentagon in the center, they are glitching really bad. No clue why, I've tried removing/changing the easing of the animation, I've tried removing different properties of the divs themselves, can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Comment: These "WYSIWYG" editors for animation in JS will provide you with bloated code... What you're trying to do isn't that hard in normal JS - especially using some libraries like Greensock and/or jQuery.

Comment: it's going to be alot more complicated than it currently is, so I'd prefer to use edge animate, although I could spend like 10 times as long coding everything by hand. I just want to figure out why this glitch is happening, when it didn't before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, basically I had created a rounded rectangle which was like 542px wide and 63px high, but then after converting it to a symbol, I wanted to resize it to 255 wide and 55 high, so instead of resizing the div within the symbol, I had resized the entire symbol. Therefore, the glitch that was taking place was that the div had two different sizes simultaneously and in firefox, it displayed both.